# Отправка через flask-socketio python параметры и файл

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, socket.io

Всем привет, помогите отправить файл и параметры через flask-socketio дело в том что есть программа которая может отправить id_case, id_docinf и images[].
я использую данный код:

```
data_file = [open(dir_file, 'rb').read(), open(dir_file, 'rb').read()]
d = MultiDict()
d.add('event', 'sendImages')
d.add('id_case', 2)
d.add('id_docinf', 4)

for image in data_file:
    d.add('images', b64encode(image))

multi  = ImmutableMultiDict(d)
socketio.emit('message', d)
```

при отправке socketio на стороне клиента видит только id_case и id_docinf, а images нет.
так же нет Content-Type и Content-Length: 0

в socketio должен быть Query String Parametr и FormData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b64encode(image).decode('UTF-8')
и все работает как нужно.